# Spring Data always returns an empty array with reactive mongo repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to build an application using reactive mongo libraries and spring data. However, every time I hit the application and use `dao.findAll()` I get an empty array of results.
Please find the code below.

`/config/MongoAdminConfig.java`

```
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class MongoAdminConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/projects"))
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "projects";
    }
}
```

`/controllers/AccountController.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("accounts")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    @GetMapping
    public Flux<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        return this.accountDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

`/dao/AccountDao.java`

```
public interface AccountDao extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Account, String> {
}
```

`/models/Account.java`

```
@Document(collection = "accounts")
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String accountNumber;
    private String type;
    private String status;
    private double availableBalance;
    private String currency;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

**Database query example**

```
> db.accounts.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb40c43e079db50337b211"), "accountNumber" : "BANK123456", "type" : "savings", "status" : "active", "availableBalance" : 10000.5, "currency" : "USD" }
> db
projects
>
```

`/pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aditapillai.demos</groupId>
    <artifactId>accounts-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/unsubd/spring-jpa-demo)

Platform Details:

OS: Ubuntu 19.04 LTS
Mongo version: 4.2.1

My mongo server is running on my local machine on port `27017`
It is a new mongo installation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by doing the following.

deleted `/config/MongoAdminConfig.java`
/Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      database: projects
```

I'll keep looking to understand what exactly happened here.